# Why can't I install mono-complete?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, mono

When I try to install it, the following result comes up:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using, did you run apt-get update before trying to install, are you using a Third party repository as the error message warn?

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. There was some third party repo giving an incorrect download.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, here is one scenario where this problem occurred for me: using the latest [Jenkins docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/), which is based on Debian 8 "jessie".

I ran the normal mono install instructions, including

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Then the `apt-get install -y mono-devel` was failing with unmet dependencies.

I tried reloading the docker image and running the install *without* the two commands above. Suddenly it worked.

Apparently the standard third party repository for mono isn't needed with the latest (as of March 30 2016) jenkins image.

Comment: This fails at present 'cause the key used for signing expired ;(